# Changing DropDown Selected Item Based on Selected Value (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a dropdown list on my page (ddlProgram) which is populated via a database query like so:

```
Using dbContext as IRFEntities = New IRFEntities
    Dim getPrograms = (From p in dbContext.IRF_Program _
                       Order By p.name _
                       Select p)
    ddlProgram.DataSource = getPrograms
    ddlProgram.DataTextField = "name"
    ddlProgram.DataValueField = "id"
    ddl.Program.DataBind()
End Using
```

So, for example, one might have a DataTextField of "Education" and an ID of "221".

Now, I prepopulate the form with information about the individual visiting the site (if available) - including the dropdown list like so:

```
If getProspect IsNot Nothing Then
  If getProspect.user_id Is Nothing Then
    ddlProgram.SelectedValue = getProspect.Program
  End If
End If
```

The Program property contains a number that matches the ID of a Program. So, for example, this individual might have a Program of "221" which would match the "221" of Education mentioned above.

Currently the application successfully sets the SelectedValue to "221" for the DropDownList (ddlProgram), but the SelectedItem of the DDL remains the same (e.g., if it is initially "History" with an ID of "1" after the prepopulation it is "History" with an ID of "221").

What I'm trying to make happen is that the SelectedItem is updated to item which corresponds with the SelectedValue. So, in the end, if the individual has "221" for "Education" selected when the form is prepopulated they would see Education as the selected item and the selected value would be set correctly, whereas right now the form is showing the wrong SelectedItem but has the right SelectedValue behind the scenes.

Here is a more complete idea of the code flow from the Page_Load event:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
        ' If prospect is coming from unique url
        Dim prospect_url As String = Page.RouteData.Values("value")
        ' Save prospect_url into session variable
        Session("prospect_url") = prospect_url
        Using dbContext As IRFEntities = New IRFEntities
            ' Prepopulate the programs dropdown.
            Dim getPrograms = (From p In dbContext.IRF_Program _
                            Order By p.name _
                             Select p)
            ddlProgram.DataSource = getPrograms
            ddlProgram.DataTextField = "name"
            ddlProgram.DataValueField = "id"
            ddlProgram.DataBind()
        End Using
        Using dbContext As IRFEntities = New IRFEntities
            ' Prepopulate the states dropdown.
            Dim getStates = (From p In dbContext.IRF_States _
                             Order By p.name _
                            Select p)
            ddlState.DataSource = getStates
            ddlState.DataTextField = "name"
            ddlState.DataValueField = "id"
            ddlState.DataBind()
        End Using
        Using dbContext As IRFEntities = New IRFEntities
            ' Grab info. about prospect based on unique url.
            Dim getProspect = (From p In dbContext.IRF_Prospects _
                              Where p.url = prospect_url _
                              Select p).FirstOrDefault
            ' If they have a record...
            If getProspect IsNot Nothing Then
                If getProspect.user_id Is Nothing Then
                    ' Prepopulate the form with their information.
                    ' These must have a value, so we need to make sure that no column is null in the database.
                    ddlProgram.SelectedValue = getProspect.program
                    txtFirst.Text = getProspect.first_name
                    txtLast.Text = getProspect.last_name
                    txtAddress.Text = getProspect.address
                    txtCity.Text = getProspect.city
                    ddlState.SelectedValue = getProspect.state
                    txtZip.Text = getProspect.zip
                    txtPhone.Text = getProspect.phone
                    txtEmail.Text = getProspect.email_address
                    txtYearEnrolling.Text = getProspect.enrolling_in
                Else
                    ' Redirect them to login.
                    Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
                End If
            End If
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you rebind in every postback?

Comment: The binding to the dropdownlist for the list of programs occurs only if the page is not a postback, the pulling in of the individual info. (including their selected program) occurs with each postback. however, the page is generally static, there shouldn't really be multiple postbacks (unless someone for whatever reason decides to refresh the page).

Comment: Add more code to show your page flow

Comment: How do you know there is a difference between the selected value and item?

Comment: I knew it b/c I would then submit the values to the database and while the selecteditem didn't appear correct on the form page it posted the correct value to the database from selectedvalue. It seems to be working now.

Comment: @AmiramKorach - Apparently I didn't fix it. It now works correctly on localhost but not when deployed to the live server. But they are using the exact same code?!?

Comment: Yes, the databases are exactly the same.

Comment: Yes. You can attach to the server w3wp process. Open "Attach to process" and set the Qualifier to the server name.

Comment: Okay, I've attached to it, but I'm not sure how to do debugging from this?

Comment: Just put a breakpoint in your code and browse the site with a browser

Comment: Did that. It now says at the breakpoint: "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." Thanks for your help.

Comment: Probably the server code is not the same as yours. Build and publish again. Stop and start iis on the server. Also when you attach see that the "Attach to:" is "Managed" and your .net version (on the iis server).

Comment: Well, I figured out what is happening. It claims to successfully be publishing the files, but they aren't getting placed there at all! I found that if I manually copy the local PackageTmp file to the server, then the site works correctly...Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you set to copy only changed files? It doesn't always work. I always copy all files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing looks like it should work. If you put a breakpoint after the setting of the value and check the SelectedItem text and value, do they appear as expected or mismatched?

Use the Immediate Window to check:

```
ddlProgram.SelectedItem.Text
ddlProgram.SelectedItem.Value
```

If they appear the same then I would presume the binding code is being refired and the list is being regenerated with the first item being selected.

To check this put a break point on the binding code and see if it is fired more than once and correct the order of the methods appropriately.

ADDED:
If it works on your local environment it should work when published, if the code is the same? Looking at your code, I'd start by seperating out some of the databinding code into seperate methods rather than have everything in Page_Load, one becuase it's good practice and two because it will make debugging easier. Further than that I'm not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: Well, this is very strange...it just started working! But your suggestion was very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Okay, let me take that back. It works correctly on the localhost but when published to the production server it doesn't work correctly - it has the error mentioned in the original question.